# mod_rewrite with name replacing ID

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a page on my website that dynamically displays content. The URL structure is `mywebsite.com/giveaway/giveaway.php?id=(any number)` 
I wish to change that dynamic URL into a static/friendly URL `mywebsite.com/giveaway/name-of-giveaway-corresponding-to-id`. 
  In my .htaccess file found in my root folder i have the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=301,L]

    # existing rule
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The current .htaccess file removes .php and also redirects and changes a URL on my site from
`mywebsite.com?page=number` to `mywebsite.com/page/number`

I know you have to get the name corresponding to the ID in php from my database and use that, but im not sure how to write the code in the .htaccess file or how to use and pass the results from the database. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that is what you mean, but you can't connect the rewrite engine, which is part of the underlying Apache server layer, to the database, which has to be accessed by php.

So you can't rewrite the "name-of-giveaway-corresponding-to-id" to the id directly, you need to rewrite it to something like giveaway.php?nameofgiveaway=(name of giveaway) and then search the database for that string.

Your way to go is to add a rewrite rule like

```
RewriteRule ^giveaway/([^/]+)$ giveaway.php?nameofgiveaway=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(not tested, so forgive me if something is wrong) and search for $_GET['nameofgiveaway'].

Comment: Ah i see. So would the dynamic url to this webpage on stackoverflow be.. stackoverflow.com/questions/?id=21203525/?name=mod-rewrite-with-name-replacing-id then they have just used mod_rewrite to change it to the current one? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sort of (except they are not using Apache but Windows IIS and thus not mod_rewrite). You got the URL wrong, though. They rewrite the URL in the browser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203525/mod-rewrite-with-name-replacing-id/21218043 - to something like http://stackoverflow.com?page=questions&id=21203525&title=mod-rewrite-with-name-replacing-id&id2=21218043. The parameter names and meanings are 100% wrong, this is just an example about rewriting. Once you are satisfied with the answer, feel free to accept it :-).