# mod_rewriting with name from database

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page with the the URL format:

`www.site.com/events/event.php?id=1&cat_id=4`

which I'd like to rewrite to something more SEO friendly, namely

`www.site.com/events/name-of-event`

(I don't need the category name in my URL, just for the page to create dynamic breadcrumb links).

I have the event name in my MySQL database, and I'd like to use that in the URL. I've tried to adapt the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21218043/3181236) but without success. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

`RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)$ event.php?event_name=$1 [L,QSA]` this is what I initially tried (the cat_id isn't essential to the URL as the page checks and retrieves a default if none is passed).

Comment: How have you adapted it? What didn't work?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is it? considering there's apparently no good answer to that question, perhaps someone might have an answer for this fresh one...

Comment: So what's this guy doing? http://moz.com/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls or this guy? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21218043/3181236

Comment: What's not working? Your rule looks fine. You have the event.php pulling the proper event from the DB using the event name? You have mod_rewrite turned on?

Answer (score 0):

For backward compatibility, you probably want to redirect `events/event.php?id=123` to the new `events/event_name` url. The problem is that, as the person said in your linked answer, there is no real way to connect to the database via Apache, so you'll have to handle the redirection/translation in the file itself.

The rule itself must look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]+)/?$ /events/event.php?event_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then, in your `event.php` you'll do something like this:

```
#This is the top line of your file.
if( isset( $_GET['id'] ) ) {
  $id = intval( $_GET['id'], 10 );
  $event_name = do_database_query_NOAW( $id );
  header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
  header( 'Location: /events/' . $event_name );
  exit();
}

#code that now uses (the sanitized) event name instead of the sanitized id
if( !isset( $_GET['event_name'] ) || !preg_match( '/[A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $_GET['event_name'] ) ) {
  header( 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' );
  exit();
}
```